# Using echo -e with backslash (\)

Tags: bash, shell, echo

I was reading about the echo command in Unix and I got confused in the -e option with the backslash (`\`) escaped characters I ran the following two examples :

```
echo "hello\\\\world"
```

output: `hello\\world`

now running the same command with the -e :

```
echo -e "hello\\\\world"
```

output: `hello\world`

so what is the meaning of the backslash character with and without the `-e` option ?

Regards

Comment: you really should avoid echo altogether: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo/65819#65819 . I now use almost always printf '%s\n' "something" instead of echo "something" (and benefit from all the other stuff printf provides, %'d,  %f,  %08d,  etc, in addition to the portability benefits and the regularity whatever the content of "something" is, as Stephane Chazelas explains in his post)

Comment: If your `echo` behaves different with `-e`, then you are not on `UNIX`. The backslach character is always an escape character for `echo` on UNIX.

Comment: @schily, ...agreed as to the first sentence of your above comment, but the second one I'm not so sure of -- XSI extensions are optional, after all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No, XSI extensions are **mandatory** if you like to call the beast `UNIX`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Bash double-quoted strings you can use backslash to make sure the next character is treated as a literal. That is, typing the argument `"a\\b"` results in passing the *literal string* `a\b` to the command. From this we can conclude that in both cases you are passing `hello\\world` as the final argument to `echo` in both cases - each pair of backslashes is expanded to a single literal backslash before passing to `echo`.

The `-e` flag to `echo` "enable[s] interpretation of the following backslash escapes" (see `help echo` for details). `\\` is listed there as an escape sequence for a single backslash, so in this case `echo` is doing the same thing Bash did with the original string and reducing two backslashes to one. The `-e` flag is mostly used to be able to include escape sequences like `\t` for a horizontal tab character or `\n` for a newline. For example:

```
$ echo -e 'first\tsecond\tthird'
first   second  third
```

I would recommend using `printf` for this instead. First, its use of a format string means that we can safely mix user-provided strings with escape sequences:

```
$ printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' 'inject\nescape' '\\' '\evil'
inject\nescape  \\  \evil
```

Second, not all versions of `echo` support `-e`, and careless use of unquoted variables will let people change `echo`'s behaviour:

```
$ injection='-e a\nb'
$ echo $injection
a
b
```

Third: [This PhD thesis-level analysis](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3645).

As a side note, Bash does *not* treat backslashes in single-quoted strings as escape characters, which is why we get the following results:

```
$ echo 'hello\\\\world'
hello\\\\world
$ echo -e 'hello\\\\world'
hello\\world
```